# Best form of audio compression / packing

Tags: audio, compression

Currently in my game I have a large amount of sounds and am getting to the point where I need to find a way to reduce the overall size of the sounds to save space when I deploy. I was wondering if there are any techniques for audio compression / packing like there is for graphics pack (DXT)?

Thanks in advance

**Edit**: The engine that I am using only supports .Wav files so I will have to be able to decompress audio back to a .Wav format

**Edit 2**: The majority of the files that I will need to compress and decompress will be sound effects and background tunes which can lose some quality. Any solution preferable needs to be open source for this.

Comment: "Best" is usually tricky in gamedev — most of our options involve different trade-offs. In this case, there's compression efficiency in terms of size, decoding speed, audio quality, and expressive range. (eg. MIDI music has fantastic compression and good audio quality, but it can't represent every music track — vocals in particular. Even further down that path there's procedural sound where you generate it at runtime from tiny seed data) There's also licensing considerations. Tell us more about your needs and what kind of sound you're compressing and we can suggest options fit to your purpose.

Comment: The majority of the sounds that I am wanting to compress are background tracks and sound effects. As far as licencing goes opensource would be what I am after.